# How to enable the hard keyboard on real device?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Despite it is working on virtual device, the hard keyboard does not work when testing my app on my real android device (Samsung galaxy i551).

I added the following configuration in the Manifest :

```
<uses-configuration android:reqHardKeyboard="true"  android:reqKeyboardType="qwerty" />
```

Any clue welcome, regards

Answer (score 0):

The hardware keyboard works automatically. No configuration is necessary to make it work. Your `<uses-configuration>` simply says that your application will *only* work on devices with hardware QWERTY keyboards.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Nevertheless, after I removed those lines, nothing has changed

Comment: @Emmanuel: Either your device is broken, or you have some extremely strange code in your project.

Comment: Well my device is almost new and I cannot find strange code, all is pretty basic. Strange thing : the hard keys that have been assigned listeners to, do work. I will test my app with another device. Thanks anyway I will keep this thread up if anything new